# Input-Output Correlations using PCA

Tags: correlation, pca, sampling, simulation

I want to understand the correlation between a set of $\color{red}{\textrm{inputs}}$ and a set of $\color{blue}{\textrm{outputs}}$ deriving from numerical simulations, and possibly reduce dimensions of my problem. A number of simulation samples $n$ was ran by randomly selecting inputs within given intervals using the Latin Hypercube sampling (LHS) method. Then, the respective outputs were stored, so I have the combination of inputs-outputs for each sample.

Since the inputs were selected via LHS method, the input-input correlation should not exist. The output-output correlation can exist, but I am more interested in the input-output correlation. It is also possible that the combination of multiple inputs affect the outputs in unexpected ways.

A correlation matrix (pearson,spearman) can identify correlations between single inputs and single outputs. But to include more complicated correlations, I am considering other tools, such as Principal Component Analysis (PCA). However, I am not sure if it's applicable, or how to interpret the results in such scenario. Let me give a concrete example.

In my specific case, there are 16 inputs and 3 outputs for $n=$5200. My first approach was to concatenate them and perform PCA in this $n \times 19$ matrix. What I found was that the first 3 principal components only explain ~35% of the observed variance, and to reach 95% I need 12 principal components. This seems to indicate that PCA is not of much help. I believe this is a symptom of the fact that there's so much variance in the inputs due to the sampling method. Then I looked at the loading factors, some of which are presented here:

PC1 (17%):
$\color{blue}{\textrm{output1=0.6}}$,
$\color{blue}{\textrm{output2=0.5}}$,
$\color{red}{\textrm{input1=0.45}}$,
$\color{red}{\textrm{input2=0.25}}$,
$\color{red}{\textrm{...(inputs)...}}$,
$\color{blue}{\textrm{output3=0.06}}$,
$\color{red}{\textrm{...(inputs)...}}$

PC2 (29%):
$\color{blue}{\textrm{output3=0.7}}$,
$\color{red}{\textrm{input2=0.6}}$,
$\color{red}{\textrm{input3=0.2}}$,
$\color{red}{\textrm{...(inputs)...}}$,
$\color{blue}{\textrm{output2=0.07}}$,
$\color{blue}{\textrm{output1=0.03}}$,
$\color{red}{\textrm{...(inputs)...}}$

PC3 (36%):
$\color{red}{\textrm{input5=0.7}}$,
$\color{red}{\textrm{input6=0.6}}$,
$\color{red}{\textrm{...(inputs)...}}$,
$\color{blue}{\textrm{output3=0.04}}$,
$\color{red}{\textrm{...(inputs)...}}$,
$\color{blue}{\textrm{output1=output2=0.03}}$,
$\color{red}{\textrm{...(inputs)...}}$

My interpretation is that PC1 informs mostly how $\color{red}{\textrm{input1}}$ and $\color{red}{\textrm{input2}}$ correlate with $\color{blue}{\textrm{output1}}$ and $\color{blue}{\textrm{output2}}$. PC2 indicates that $\color{blue}{\textrm{output3}}$ is mostly correlated with $\color{red}{\textrm{input2}}$ and $\color{red}{\textrm{input3}}$. Then, PC3 seems to correlate only the $\color{red}{\textrm{inputs}}$ with themselves, but this is an useless information and not at all expected (due to LHS). Should it be ignored then?

Regardless, at this level I am still al 36% of explained variance. So it seems that the correlations are either very small or non-linear. Can someone point out if I am missing something about PCA, or if it is not appropriate in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure PCA is suited for what you want, normally you would use PCA with inputs only, and see how the components predict outputs.
Something like demixed PCA might work, using output as task parameter  (https://elifesciences.org/articles/10989)

Comment: Thank you for the reference. However, don't you mean PCA would be only applicable to the outputs, since the inputs should not have any correlation due to LHS?